# httpPost Not Found from Ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, http-post

My asp.net httpPost is not working from AJAX request.

My controller:

```
[Route("api/sendData")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(PostData data)
    {

        return true;
    }
}
```

My PostData:

```
public class PostData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My AJAX request from html file:

```
var data = {
        Id : 1
    };
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "api/sendData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                console.debug(result);
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                console.debug(xhr);
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                alert(err);
            }
        });
```

I don't know why it is returning 404 Not Found. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is it something wrong in my ajax?

Answer (score 1):

The [`RouteAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) should be apply on top of action method name instead of controller class, so that the action method becomes this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/sendData")]
    public bool Post(PostData data)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to use attribute routing on controller class level, [`RoutePrefixAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) should be used instead.

Additionally, if you want to pass properties inside object model, you need to use `JSON.stringify` and set `contentType: "application/json"` as you want to send JSON object into action method:

```
<script>
    var data = { Id: 1, 
                 // other properties 
               };
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/sendData",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            console.debug(result);
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            // error handling here
        }
    });
</script>
```